# RCA monitor won't display highest resolution when NVidia drivers are installed

Tags: windows-7, drivers, resolution

My computer is a dual-monitor setup. It won't display my second monitor's highest res... In fact, it will only display one resolution. Anything higher or lower makes the monitor not show the screen.

I've had this problem with this computer, and I upgraded almost all my components (CPU, RAM, motherboard and video card included) and I still have this problem with my new setup. This leads me to believe it's a problem with my monitor and the NVidia driver together.

Any thoughts on what can be done? The manufacturer of the monitor doesn't make a driver for this monitor.

I used to run Windows Vista and now my new setup runs Windows 7.

Relevant specs:
RCA RS95 monitor
NVidia GTX460